# Android library pass unknown object from another library without dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library

I maintain a library for Android which uses our platform and also simplifies many things developers do. One of those things are push messages. We get user Firebase token and register it on our server and use it to send messages. I want to simplify token work, so developers don't need to manually get token.

For that I need to implement something like detectToken(), but I'd need to get FirebaseMessaging object as a parameter. And my library has no idea of this class unless I add it as a dependency. Can I do that without adding FCM library as a dependency to my library? I know I can use implementation instead of api in gradle, but this still forces developers to include FCM library if they don't need it.

I think this is probably doable with reflection and passing Any class, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: "forces developers to include FCM library if they don't need it.". Your library uses it so they do in fact need it I would think. And I wouldn't worry much if you think it will increase their app size much because if they make an app with minifyEnabled, like most developers do, it should strip out all unused classes and only include the FirebaseMessaging class

Comment: @IvoBeckers the thing is that our library has a lot of modules and not everyone need, say, push messaging. so you think best way would be to include FCM via api in gradle and let developers strip my chunky lib with minify? alright, thanks. I'll consider that. only downside I see for now is that it will increase the size of our aar file.